# Retornar variáveis locais da função

Tags: c, array, funções, return, gerenciamento-de-memória

Tenho dois métodos:

```
// Apenas define um vetor de 4 posições e retorna ele
int *verticesFromFace(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
  int vertices[4] = {v1, v2, v3, v4};
  return &(vertices);
}

// pega um cubo e uma face dele, retorna um vetor de vertices daquela face
Vertice *getPointsFromFace(Cube c, Face f) {
  Vertice points[4];
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < FACE_VERTICES; i++)
    points[i] = c.vertices[f.vertices[i] - 1];

  return &(points);
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
// pega uma face do cubo, armazena nela o vetor de vértices (usando aquele método) e também as cores daquela face (3 últimos parâmetros)
createFace(c.faces[0], verticesFromFace(1, 2, 3, 4), 1, 0, 0);


// Um vetor de vertices, quando chamo o metodo com o cubo e uma face do cubo
Vertice *points = getPointsFromFace(c, c.faces[i]);
```

O GCC retorna o erro:

> **warning:** function returns address of local variable
>   [-Wreturn-local-addr]    return &(points[0]);

Embora seja um **warning**, o código não funciona pois a variável local não é retornada. Como posso corrigir isso?

P.S.: Esse `&()` no retorno foi uma tentativa que fiz, quando vi uma postagem no Stack Overflow Inglês

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso. O *array* é alocado na *stack*, quando a função termina ele não pode mais ser acessado.

O pior é que em C até pode em algumas circunstâncias do qual você não tem controle e isso pode ser trágico porque a maioria dos programadores acham que se testar e funcionar está certo. Toda linguagem tem essas coisas, mas C tem muito mais. C permite fazer muita coisa errada e parecer que está certa. Por sorte nesse caso deu errado antes que fosse tarde.

Entenda [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Para manter o valor "vivo" quando sai da função precisa alocar o objeto no *heap*. Isso é feito com [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc). E depois você tem que liberá-lo com `free()`. Muito programador experiente escorrega e deixa memória vazar. Ou pode tentar liberar o que já foi liberado, o que pode ser trágico. Programador iniciante costuma nem se preocupar com isso porque "funciona" sem ele.

Todo esse código está errado. Seria algo assim:

```
int *verticesFromFace(int v1, int v2, int v3, int v4) {
    int *vertices = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    //inicaliza os elementos aqui
    return vertices;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/ToReturn.c).

## Alocação assimétrica

Na verdade o ideal é nem fazer isso, é alocar a memória onde precisa daquele dado, assim fica mais fácil acompanhar seu fluxo e evita esquecer de chamar o `free()`. Não fazer isso é praticamente pedir para criar confusão, fica assimétrico.

Cada função deve ser "dona" de seu objeto por completo (`malloc()` e `free()` devem vir em pares, ela deve ser declarada, alocada e liberada no meu local. Todas as APIs do C e de todo programador C que entende o problema trabalha dessa forma. Função não deve alocar memória para retornar para outros, ela deve receber um *buffer* alocado para manipulá-lo.

Claro que tem caso para alocar no próprio local, mas só pode usar isso se souber muito bem o que está fazendo, tenha um motivo muito forte e saiba que terá que ter atenção redobrada para gerenciar a memória.

## *Warnings*

*Warnings* são erros que não impedem a compilação, só isso. O fato dele não parecer um erro não quer dizer que não seja.

Comment: Consegui aqui, obrigado, só tive que mudar de vetor de 4 para ponteiro aí no `malloc`. No caso a liberação será feita na variável que recebe o retorno? Exemplo : `Vertice *points = getPointsFromFace(c, c.faces[i])` .... `free(points)`

Comment: Isso mesmo. Não entendi o que teve que mudar.

Comment: De `int vertices[4] = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));` para `int *vertices = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Ah, tá certo, eu comi bola nisso mesmo.