# Multiplicação de duas matrizes em C. Transferência de valores entre funções

Tags: c

Há pouco tempo foi-me dado um projecto de `multiplicação de matrizes, onde tenho duas funções: uma **"main"**, e outra **"produto_de_duas matrizes"**; a main, vai ler o  os diferentes valores dos elementos das duas matrizes a
multiplicar definidos pelo utilizador e escreverá o resultado do produto das duas matrizes. E a produto_de_duas matrizes, vai receber valores da função main devolverá o resultado do produto das duas matrizes à função main que escreverá esse resultado no ecrã e num ficheiro criado para servir de memória futura das várias execuções do programa.

Eu não entendo como é se passam os valores de uma função para a outra. Alguém me consegue explicar?´

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int linhasA, colunasA, linhasB, colunasB;
int l, c;

void main()
{
    char metodo;

    /*Título do Programa / Apresentação */
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tPRODUTO DE DUAS MATRIZES \n \n");
    printf("Trabalho realizado por:\n");
    printf("Francisco Pinto, n%c 43487\n", 248);
    printf("Turno pr%ctico\n", 160);
    printf("Turma 22D\n \n \n");

    /*Menu onde o utlizador poderá escolher como irá importar os dados relativos às matrizes*/
    printf("MENU PRINCIPAL \n");
    printf("============ \n");
    printf("Selecione, por favor o m%ctodo desejado para a importa%c%co dos dados:\n", 130, 135, 198);
    printf("==================================================\n");
    printf("\tA) Atrav%cs do TECLADO\n", 130);
    printf("\tB) Importando um FICHEIRO\n\n");
    printf("\tC) Se desejar sair do programa");
    scanf(" %c", &metodo);


    do
    {
        scanf(" %c", &metodo);
        metodo = toupper(metodo); /*Converte todas as letras inseridas pelo utilizador para maiúsclas*/
    } while ((metodo != 'A') && (metodo != 'B') && (metodo != 'C')); /*Caso o utilizador tenha escolhido letras diferentes a A), B) ou C), o menu aparece até que o utilizador escolha a letra certa */

    switch (metodo) /*Escohe o caso */
    {
    case 'A': /*Se o utilizador escolher a opção A)*/
        printf("\n\n");

        /*Dados da matriz A, preenhidos pelo utilizador*/
        printf("Qual o n%cmero de linhas da Matriz A?\n", 163);
        scanf(" %d", &linhasA);
        printf("Qual o n%cmero de colunas da Matriz A?\n", 163);
        scanf(" %d", &colunasA);
        printf("\n\n");

        /*Dados da matriz B, preenhidos pelo utilizador*/
        printf("Qual o n%cmero de colunas da Matriz B?\n", 163);
        scanf(" %d", &linhasB);
        printf("Qual o n%cmero de colunas da Matriz B ?\n", 163);
        scanf(" %d", &colunasB);

        float A[linhasA][colunasA], B[linhasB][colunasB];

        do
        {
            scanf(" %d", linhasA);
            scanf(" %d", colunasA);
            scanf(" %d", linhasB);
            scanf(" %d", colunasB);

            if (colunasA != linhasB);

            printf("\t***ERRO***");
            printf("Como o n%cmero de colunas da matriz A %c diferente do n%cmero de linhas da matriz B, n%co %c poss%cvel fazer a multiplica%c%co \n\n", 163, 130, 163, 198, 130, 141, 135, 198);
        } while (colunasA != linhasB);

        if (colunasA = linhasB)

            /*Carregamento da matriz A*/
            printf("\tDados da matriz A: \n");

        for (l = 0; l <= linhasA - 1; l++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c <= colunasA - 1; l++);
            printf("A[%d][%d] = ", l + 1, c + 1);
            scanf("%f", &A[l][c]);
        }

        /*Carregamento da matriz B*/
        printf("\tDados da matriz B: \n");

        for (l = 0; l <= linhasB - 1; l++)
        {
            for (c = 0; c <= colunasB - 1; l++);
            printf("B[%d][%d] = ", l + 1, c + 1);
            scanf("%f", &B[l][c]);
        }
        {

    case 'B':  /*Se o utilizador escolher a opção B)*/
    {

    }

    case 'C':  /*Se o utilizador escolher a opção C)*/
    {

    }




    system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Este trecho: do
  {
   scanf(" %d", linhasA);
   scanf(" %d", colunasA);
   scanf(" %d", linhasB);
   scanf(" %d", colunasB);
 não tem sentido, você já leu estas variáveis.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Retornar variáveis locais da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164705/retornar-vari%c3%a1veis-locais-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score -1):

Francisco, essa passagem de valores, em C, pode ser através do comando`return` ou de manipulação de ponteiros. No seu caso, acredito que o `return` seja melhor. Ficaria algo assim:

```
int* produto_de_duas_matrizes(int *matriz1, int *matriz2, int tamanho){

    int matriz_resultado[tamanho]

    //Aqui você insere o código responsável pela multiplicação de matrizes
    //Você pode manipular ela como vetores: matriz1[posicao]
    //Ou como ponteiro: *(matriz1 + (posicao * sizeof(int)))

    return matriz_resultado
}
```

E na função main, você deve receber o resultado dessa função também em um ponteiro:

```
int main(){

    //tamanho deve ser substituído pelo tamanho que você precisa
    int matriz1[<tamanho>], matriz2[<tamanho>];
    int *matriz_resultado;
    int aux;
    //Trecho de código para popular as duas matrizes

    matriz_resultado = produto_de_duas_matrizes(matriz1, matriz2);

    for(aux = 0; aux < tamanho; aux++){
        printf("%d\n", *(matriz_resultado + (aux * sizeof(int))))
    }
}
```

Eu não me lembro bem como é que se calcula o produto de duas matrizes, por isso não coloquei o código disso para você, mas se não estiver funcionando dessa forma que eu te falei, poste seu código aqui que eu te ajudo a manipular os valores entre as funções.

Comment: O que eu tenho até agora é o seguinte:

Comment: @FranciscoWaitFor-itPinto, funcionou? Caso não tenha funcionado, coloque seu código na pergunta para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: já aí está. Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: `matriz_resultado` é uma variável local da função `produto_de_duas_matrizes`. Retornar um ponteiro para ela desse jeito não deve funcionar.